# Custom mouse animation on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I have been looking to implement a mouse to change when hovering over a link and have not come across guides on how to implement this.

I was looking for something like this website: 
https://www.niccolomiranda.com/about when you hover over the link it increases the area of the circle.

If someone help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried: this is not a free code writing service. The best way to learn is actually to inspect the code of the site itself, if you want to reproduce whatever effect you're seeing. Dig into the JS. Open dev tools and put break points in the code to see what's going on. We can't help people who refuse to help themselves by doing the most basic learning themselves. See how to [create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps to you:

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    
    $('.cursor').eq(0).css({
        left: e.clientX,
        top: e.clientY
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cursor').eq(1).css({
          left: e.clientX,
          top: e.clientY
      });
    }, 100);
})
 
$("a").on("mouseenter", function () {
  $('.cursor-a').addClass("active");
  $('.cursor-v').addClass("active");
});

$("a").on("mouseleave", function () {
  $('.cursor-a').removeClass("active");
  $('.cursor-v').removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
    cursor: none;
}

body {
  background: #000;
}

.cont {
  padding: 40px;
}
.link {
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  padding-top:20px;
}

.cursor {
    position: fixed;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1000;
}


.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  
}
  
.cursor-a  {
        position: fixed;
        background-color: #5C6AFF;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        z-index: 10000;
        transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.75, -1.27, 0.3, 2.33) transform, 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.27, 0.3, 1.33) opacity;
        user-select: none;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index: 100000000;
        transform: scale(1);
    }

.cursor-a.active {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transform: scale(0);
    }
.cursor-b {
    position: fixed;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.75, -1.27, 0.3, 2.33) transform, 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.27, 0.3, 1.33) opacity;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 10000000;
    transform: translate(-14px, -14px);
}

.cursor-v {
    width: 38px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.75, -1.27, 0.3, 2.33) transform, 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.27, 0.3, 1.33) opacity;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: white;
}

    .cursor-v.active {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        opacity: 0.8;
        transform: scale(2);
        border:none;
    }
```

```html
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cursor cursor-a"></div>
<div class="cursor cursor-b"><div class="cursor-v"></div></div>

<div class="cont">
   <a class="link" href="#">custom link, hover me!</a>
</div>
```

**[MAGIC FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/20yco/yLzua9xh/1/)**